# Dataframe compare three columns and find mismatched

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following code

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, on=['column1','column2','column3'], how='right', indicator=True)

    # Filter rows where the indicator column is 'left_only' or 'right_only'
    mismatched_rows = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'right_only'] #.isin(['left_only', 'right_only'])]
    
    # Drop the indicator column
    mismatched_rows = mismatched_rows.drop('_merge', axis=1)
    
    # Display the mismatched rows
    #print(mismatched_rows)
    mismatched_rows.to_csv(file_name + "_output_mismatched.csv",index=False)
```

The above code is matching with index as well,  for eg.

```
in dataframe 1, 
column1 column2 column3
x         y       z
a         b       c

in dataframe 2, 
column1 column2 column3
a         b       c
x         y       z
```

in above dataframe for column2 value y and column3 value z is matching with coulmn1 x, the only difference is it is second row.
but still above code giving both rows as mismatched.

how can we get both rows matched
Thanks

Comment: Maybe please make sure to use consistent dataframe names (1 / 2 / old / new) and provide an expected output for [mre]. You may also remove the csv-writing part from your post since that does not appear to be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df_old = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['x', 'a'], 
                      'column2': ['y', 'b'], 
                      'column3': ['z', 'c'], })
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'x'], 
                      'column2': ['b', 'y'], 
                      'column3': ['c', 'z'], })

merged_df = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, on=['column1','column2','column3'], how='right', indicator=True)

# Filter rows where the indicator column is 'left_only' or 'right_only'
mismatched_rows = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'right_only'] #.isin(['left_only', 'right_only'])]

# Drop the indicator column
mismatched_rows = mismatched_rows.drop('_merge', axis=1)

# Display the mismatched rows
print(mismatched_rows)
```

Results in

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [column1, column2, column3]
Index: []
```

Pandas Version 2.0.1

Check your pandas version.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you seem to have the first line of code doing what you seek, but then might misinterpret your merge request a little bit.

**First, reproducing your code**
Starting from identical input data:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['column1','column2','column3'],
                    data =   [['x',      'y',      'z'],
                              ['a',      'b',      'c']])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['column1','column2','column3'],
                    data =   [['a',      'b',      'c'],
                              ['x',      'y',      'z']])
```

Your first line's output:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df_2, df_1, 
                     on=['column1','column2','column3'], 
                     how='right', 
                     indicator=True)

  column1 column2 column3 _merge
0       x       y       z   both
1       a       b       c   both
```

Then you seek to filter by "right_only", however "both" lines were a match.

**Explanation:**
Quoting you: *"The above code is matching with index as well"*

Yet it will not, because: Check out [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> The join is done on columns or indexes. If joining columns on columns, the DataFrame indexes will be ignored.

You request a join on columns, hence index is ignored.

So, when you ask *"how can we get both rows matched"*, well you already have it. "Both" lines were a match, and it is not clear what mad you think otherwise.

For further help,

- please take care to provide a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including desired output because your question is not 100% clear.
- Some reading [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/12846804)